# Re-add value into EXTRA_OECONF_<name> after it was removed by EXTRA_OECONF_remove_<name>

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

To configure a component I need to add **--enable-feature** into **EXTRA_OECONF_somename**
So I tried to do:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append_somename = --enable-feature
```

But it did not help. After investigation it was found that the one of the third-party recipe contains the following line:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_remove_somename = --enable-feature
```

I can't modify the third-party recipe.

Is there a way to add **--enable-feature**  into **EXTRA_OECONF_somename**

Thank you.

Comment: Where does that third-party recipe come from? A public layer?

Comment: yes. you may say so. We have no rights to change it.

Comment: Well, do you have a name and link for the layer? I'm worst case, you'll have to fork it. The best would be to fix the layer, but providing patches for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. The _remove operations are always applied last so there is no way to undo them. I would say that the original recipe shouldn't be using it - _remove is intended for distro policy where you want to say "I don't care how this item got in the value, just remove it".

For preference the original recipe should instead it should be using PACKAGECONFIG to control addition (or not) of this feature.

Comment: Is there any way to remove value from _remove temporary storage?

Comment: No, you'll have to fork the layer for that. This, what layer is it? And what recipe?